# (Excel 2013/Non-VBA) Format Data column based on value of another cell?

Tags: excel

We have a column that is query driven, and the query partially formats the values in the column using math based off the value of a "user entry cell" on another sheet.

For the really curious, our query looks like this:

```
DECLARE @rotationsNum INT
SET @rotationsNum = ?
SELECT  t.Piece_ID, t.Linear_Location, ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 
Linear_Location) -1 )%@rotationsNum )*(360/@rotationsNum) AS Rotation FROM 
(SELECT Position.Feature_Key, Piece_ID, ((Place-1)%(Places/@rotationsNum))+1 AS Linear_Location, Place, Measured_Value, Places FROM Fake.dbo.Position LEFT JOIN Fake.dbo.Features 
ON Position.Feature_Key = Features.Feature_Key WHERE Position.Inspection_Key_FK = (SELECT Inspection_Key FROM Fake.dbo.Inspection WHERE Op_Key = ?)) AS t 
ORDER BY Piece_ID, Linear_Location
```

The first parameter "@rotationsNum" is a cell that will always have a value between 1-4.  IF the value is 1, the entire column will show "0"s, which we want to show as "N/A".  However, it isn't as simple as ["How to hide zero data.."](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2031-excel-hide-zero-data-labels.html) Because if the "@rotationsNum" == 2, 3, or 4, there will still be 0 values in the column that *need* to be shown.

A "@rotationsNum" value of 2 will have the query write the column as such: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhLcA.jpg)

So I am trying to come up with a way to format the column =IF(cell>1, do nothing, overwrite entire column to say "NA"). But I don't think it is that straight forward since the column is query driven.

Answer (score 0):

My resolution was to format the column so that if the cell that drives the "@rotationsNum" parameter is below 2, then the whole column just gets "grayed out". It kind of makes it look like a redaction, and isn't as desirable as "NA", but it works for our purposes. Hopefully this solution helps someone else who stumbles upon this problem.